# How to stop a css slide animation (starting on load) when user scrolls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, scroll

There's a trick in JS I can't achieve, it relies on stopping a slidding animation made in CSS. In the moment, I have a long div with a random images content that slides in from the top and then out from the bottom. The animation runs at page load thanks to a 'slide down' class, calling the desired slide effect. I also set a scroll effect that allows the user to scroll in this div, BUT I'd like the scroll to take priority over the animation. The animation is finally only a way to encourage the user to scroll. I tried the following code but it has no effect :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
('#scroller').removeClass("slidedown");
});
```

Could that be linked to the animation, like if it was considered as a 'scroll action' ? I attempt to handle this with 'if (ScrollTop < = >)' parameters but it simply has no effect or it just cancels the animation, which is unwanted.
'.on('mousewheel', function(){' doesn't seem to work. Replace '$(window)' by $('#scroller') has no effect either. I'm just thinking on the best way to settle this, but I need at least some advices to understand what I'm doing wrong (and I have to precise that I'm a beginner) !

Please find some key codes below :

```
----
HTML
----

<div id="scroller-wrapper">
   <div id="scroller" class="slidedown">
         <div id="img-defile1" class="img-defile">
            <img src="img/ceaac.jpg"/>
         </div>
         <div id="img-defile2" class="img-defile">
            <img src="img/ceaac2.jpg"/>
         </div>
   </div>
</div>


---
CSS
---

#scroller-wrapper {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:102vw;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    transform: scale(1, -1);
    z-index:2;
}

#scroller {
    max-width:100%;
    width:60%; 
    height:1250%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:800;
    display:block;
    transform: scale(1, -1);
}

.slidedown {
 animation-duration:120s;
 animation-name: slidedown;
 animation-timing-function:linear;
 animation-iteration-count:1;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes slidedown {

 0% {
          bottom: -75%;
      }

 100% {
          bottom: 1150%;
      }
}

.img-defile {
display:block;
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
}

.img-defile img {
width:600px;
}

.custom-scroll {
  height: calc(80% - 20px);
}


---------
JS/Jquery
---------

$('#scroller').scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('#scroller').addClass("custom-scroll");
        return false;
        } else {
        $('#scroller').removeClass("custom-scroll");
        }
});


$('.img-defile').each(function(i) {
    $pT=$("#scroller").height();
    $pL=$("#scroller").width();
    $(this).css({
        top:Math.floor(Math.random()*$pT),
        left:Math.round(Math.random()*$pL)
        });
});
```

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Check out [this article](https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/)

Comment: Thank you ! I'll check this out !